# 70's or perhaps 80's sci-fi movie with a "vaporizer" gun and a black man with robot hand

Tags: story-identification

Searching for a movie from my childhood. I remember this:

- A villain had a microwave gun/water vaporizer.
- A black guy with a prosthetic robot hand helping the villain.
- The villain uses the vaporizer gun agains a van full of nuns. The nuns die and dry out the bodies.
- In the end somewhere in a mountain in a snow area the villain defeated using a mirror and turning the microwave rays against him.

Comment: If the current answer is correct, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

"Death Ray 2000"(1981 TV movie)

This was a 1981 television movie which was a pilot for a series called "A Man Called Sloane"(1981), which ran for 1 season and had a different leading man(Robert Conrad).It had Ji-Tu Cumbuka as one of the villains, called 'Torque', who had a mechanical hand. He later reforms and becomes the sidekick to the good guy when the series began. Below is a section of the 1st user review from IMDb, which details the plot.

**"The U.S. military has developed a 'dehydrator' which is capable of turning people into skeletons. When said machine is stolen by fake nuns in the pay of KARTEL villain Erik Clawson, Priority One U.N.I.T. agent Thomas Remington Sloane The Third is put on the case. 
Surviving an attack by poisonous snakes, he travels to Lucerne, where Clawson, aided by his cybernetic-handed henchman Torque ( Ji-Tu Cumbuka ) plans to cause global chaos by wiping out the World Disarmament Council."**

Below is the IMDb page for the pilot movie.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082248/?ref_=rvi_tt

You can watch the entire movie in 10 different parts on YouTube, but I posted an NBC Thursday Night Movie promo below, which includes shots of the microwave gun.

**

Comment: That blurb....it's like they were actively trying to fit as many spy movie cliches into one paragraph as possible.

Comment: @Irishpanda, I think that was exactly what they were doing.